# How to update collections of entities in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity called Menu which contains collection of Category entity, which contains collection of Product entity.

```
$menu->fillMenu($categoriesData);
```

`$categoriesData` contains all categories and products in an array. `fillMenu` function is updating categories and products, adding new categories and products, and deleting categories and products which are not in `$categoriesData`. But this function is only working on collections in memory, not on database. So I added code:

```
foreach ($menu->getCategories() as $category) {
       foreach ($category->getProducts() as $product) {
           $em->persist($product);
       }
       $em->persist($category);
   }
$em->flush();
```

Now all updated and new categories and products are saved in database but how to remove categories and products which were deleted by `fillMenu` function? Is there any possibility get reference to deleted objects from collections and then code would be:

```
$em->remove($deletedCategory);
```

**EDIT**

I think, that I should return all entities to be deleted by `fillMenu` function. And then iterate through them and do `$em->remove($entity)`. But I think it's not very nice way. What do you think, what is the proper way to do this operation in Symfony2?

Answer (score 2):

Try $em->flush() after loop

```
foreach ($menu->getCategories() as $category) {
        foreach ($category->getProducts() as $product) {
            $em->persist($product);
        }
        $em->persist($category);
    }

$em->flush();
```

Comment: There is $em->flush(); I did not paste it.

Answer (score 0):

First, while you are updating a record or removing you don't need to persist it just you can call `$em->remove($object);` then `$em->flush();`
Second, you can do it by coding but I would recommend to let deleting be done by Doctrine; in this case you just need to change the mapping and use `onDelete="CASCADE"`
Since I don't know your mapping I can provide some sample:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $category;
```

Now when you run the following code your child products will be removed, too

```
foreach ($menu->getCategories() as $category) {
   $em->remove($category);
}
$em->flush();
```